# A "draft-box" facility

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Would it be possible for users to have a draft (i.e. save before posting) facility on the site? I frequently find myself interrupted in the middle of answers and am obliged to abandon my efforts and what I have done up to that point is wasted and/or forgotten.

I think that it would be convenient to be able to save draft answers in a personal "sandbox" for completion at a later time. The number of drafts that one is allowed save could be commensurate with one's reputation (say one draft per 500 rep).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This already happens, for one answer per site:

- [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

For related requests to make this work better, see:

- [List of my open draft-answer edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157288/list-of-my-open-draft-answer-edits)
- [Expand draft feature to allow multiple drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/expand-draft-feature-to-allow-multiple-drafts)